# I'm trying to find the the voltage across the capacitor before and after closing the switch and graph the response

Tags: capacitor

This is the initial circuit
[image]

After some simplification the circuit changed into this
[image]

Then for solving the for the switch open I simplified even further

[image]
So For t=-0 -> ic(0)=0

Using mesh current analysis

```
                 72-15i-30i=0
                 30i-Vc(0)=0   Therefore, Vc(0)=48V
```

Now for the switch closed the circuit looks like this[image]

I have tried using mesh current analysis but I always seem to have too many unknowns.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm trying to find the the voltage across the capacitor before and
>   after closing the switch and graph the response*

You got the switch open voltage right at 48 volts: -

> *Therefore, Vc(0)=48V*

For the closed switch consider this: -

[image]

The total voltage after after charging is determined by this potential divider: -

$$\dfrac{20}{20 + 15 + 6.4912} = 0.482$$

Hence the final voltage is 34.706 volts.

This means the capacitor discharges from 48 volts to 34.706 volts (13.294 volts) hence: -

$$V_C = 34.706 + 13.294\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}$$

The "R" bit is a little tricky if you don't know how to find it but, simply put it's the Thévenin resistance looking into the capacitor terminals with the capacitor removed and the 72 volt supply shorted hence: -

$$R_{TH} = 20 \text{ kohm} || (6.4912 \text{ kohm} + 15 \text{ kohm}) = 10.359\text{ kohm}$$

Answer (score 0):

The switch closed circuit simplifies to this, (10K and 18.5K in parallel, then that in series with the 15K)

meaning your capacitor ends up at ~34.7V, how it gets there will be an RC curve.

[image]